# Zend Framework product catalog routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-controller-router

I need some help to build routes for my product catalog. I whant to have urls something like this:

> /products/electronics/14
>
> /products/electronics/computers
>
> /products/electronics/computers/laptops/4

Last numbers in urls shows current listing page number.

Comment: One important point you may notice in both answers below, we've both used a controller named "product" and not "products". This is to avoid conflicts with the default router.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to define your own custom routes (i prefer regex for that because of it's speed).

I assume that you have 3 levels of categories - if you need more write a loop to create routes for you. Modify controllers and actions for your need. I assumed that page param is required - if not modify regexps.

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

//main category route
$router->addRoute(
    'category_level_0',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '/products/(\w+)/(\d+)',
        array(
            'controller' => 'product',
            'action'     => 'category',
            'module'     => 'default'
        ),
        array(
            1 => 'category_name',
            2 => 'page_nr'
        ),
        '/products/%s/%d'
    )
);

//sub category route
$router->addRoute(
    'category_level_1',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '/products/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\d+)',
        array(
            'controller' => 'product',
            'action'     => 'category',
            'module'     => 'default'
        ),
        array(
            1 => 'category_name',
            2 => 'sub_category_name'
            3 => 'page_nr'
        ),
        '/products/%s/%s/%d'
    )
);

//sub sub category route :)
$router->addRoute(
    'category_level_2',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '/products/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\d+)',
        array(
            'controller' => 'product',
            'action'     => 'category',
            'module'     => 'default'
        ),
        array(
            1 => 'category_name',
            2 => 'sub_category_name'
            3 => 'sub_sub_category_name'
            4 => 'page_nr'
        ),
        '/products/%s/%s/%s/%d'
    )
);
```

Comment: +1 I forgot the regex router is faster than the standard. Seeing as you would need to define regex parameter matching (see my answer), this answer is the better one.

Comment: Might want to set default page numbers to `1`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add multiple routes, something like

```
$router->addRoute('level1cat', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'products/:cat1/:page',
    array(
        'controller' => 'product',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'page'       => 1
    ),
    array(
        'cat1' => '\w+',
        'page' => '\d+'
    )
));

$router->addRoute('level2cat', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'products/:cat1/:cat2/:page',
    array(
        'controller' => 'product',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'page'       => 1
    ),
    array(
        'cat1' => '\w+',
        'cat2' => '\w+',
        'page' => '\d+'
    )
));

$router->addRoute('level3cat', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'products/:cat1/:cat2/:cat3/:page',
    array(
        'controller' => 'product',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'page'       => 1
    ),
    array(
        'cat1' => '\w+',
        'cat2' => '\w+',
        'cat3' => '\w+',
        'page' => '\d+'
    )
));
```

You may want to use different controller actions per route, it's up to you how you actually handle the data.

Note, this is totally untested and is just my best guess at the moment (working in .NET right now, can't even mock it up)